# Title in capital letters in the timeline and in review queues

Tags: support, design

I was checking the [timeline of a question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/81148/timeline) when I found out the title shows in capital letters:

> TIMELINE FOR [HOW TO HANDLE A HIGHLY PRODUCTIVE EMPLOYEE BUT WHO REACTS EXTREMELY EMOTIONALLY TO CODE REVIEWS?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/81148/17590)

I initially thought that this could well be because of an original upper case title, but it is not the case.

Then, I checked a couple of timelines more and this happens also: [1](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/81228/timeline), [2](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/12404/timeline), as well as in the answers: [1](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/81235/timeline), [2](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/12411/timeline).

I also noticed the title shows in capital letters in the review queues. See it in a [close vote](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/close/52060) and [first posts](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/52059):

[image]

This is not happening in other Stack Exchange sites I checked.

Comment: How do you view a timeline? Does this happen on all questions, or just some of them?

Comment: @DavidK this is one of the [unlinked pages](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76569/209901). All posts have a timeline. Just get its ID and then open `posts/ID/timeline`. For example, this post's timeline is http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/4127/timeline

Comment: @fedorqui that's pretty cool. I really need to delve more into the SE api stuff.

Comment: @ChristopherEstep you'll probably love [magic links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/209901) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am going to assume that this is because the font for page headers at the Workplace is an all-caps font.

- [TOP QUESTIONS](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/)
- [TAGS](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/tags)
- [USERS](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/users)
- [UNANSWERED QUESTIONS](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/unanswered)
- [HELP CENTER](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help)

Unlike at other sites, which use upper and lower case

- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) and [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41029159/timeline)
- [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/) and [timeline](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/6340/timeline)
- [Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/) and [timeline](https://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/84190/timeline)

The [timeline pages](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/104272/timeline) at [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/), which also uses an all-caps font for headers, would seem to confirm this.

Comment: This can well be the case!! The case of [diy.se] seems to confirm it.

Comment: Yeah, the CSS styling is actually applying the uppercase in some of those places (probably all of them, but I haven't gone looking).  It appears to be intentional.

Comment: @MonicaCellio yes, there is this `.subheader h1` that has a `text-transform: uppercase`. Glad to know this was intentional, thanks! Note it looks cool in the front page, etc, but for _timeline_ and _review_ it looks like they are shouting to us :)